# Bound mismatch when using <Item extends java.lang.Comparable<Item>>

Tags: java, generics, comparable

`Bound mismatch: The type Integer is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Item extends Comparable<Item>> of the type BTNode<Item>`

This is where I am getting the error:

```java
public class BinaryTree<Integer> {
  private BTNode<Integer> root;
  //...
}
```

This is the class I am using:

```java
public class BTNode<Item extends java.lang.Comparable<Item>> implements java.lang.Comparable<BTNode<Item>> {
  private Item data;
  //...
}
```

I think the `Integer` wrapper should satisfy the condition `<xx extends Comparable<xx>>`.
Is my understanding wrong? Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Just for the record, I am using `java.lang.Comparable` and not my own implementation of `Comparable`.

Comment: Don't name your parameters with existing class names, this is confusing you. Use letters instead, such as T or E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
public class BinaryTree<Integer> {
    private BTNode<Integer> root;
}
```

The class parameter is named `Integer`. When declaring `BTNode<Integer>`, you are not referencing `java.lang.Integer` but the parameter instead.

I don't really know what you're trying to do, but one advice: better use one single letter to name your classes parameters. For example, no error occurs when using:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> {
    private BTNode<Integer> root;
}
```

If you wanted `root` to really use the class parameter, then:

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private BTNode<T> root;
}
```

Have a look at the following lesson: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html